# How listview delete data in database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

I have a problem to delete data in listview, I was able to delete data in listview select record, but data which selected is not deleted in the database, I have a source code

```
Private _updateinputalltrans As Boolean

Private Sub btndelete_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndelete.Click
        With Me.listviewpos.SelectedItem
            .Remove()
        End With
        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure delete this record?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, New EventHandler(AddressOf DeleteData))
    End Sub

Private Sub DeleteData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim conn As New Connection(Connectiondb)
        If Me.updateinputalltrans = False Then
            If Me.listviewpos.Items.Count > 0 Then
                For Each del As ListViewItem In listviewpos.Items
                    conn.delete_dtpospart(del.Text)
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

delete_dtpospart a declare which connection to the database using a stored procedure

Comment: 2 things, I have never seen someone call a sub from a messagebox like that. Have you put a breakpoint in the DeleteData sub to make sure it is running. I would have just done an IF on the messagebox.show and if yes, then run the sub. Second, first you removed the item from the list in the button click, then iterate through the list to delete the items. Isn't it already gone, and therefore you dont fall into then for each??

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will help you to solve your problem

```
Dim Button = MessageBox.Show _
        ("Are you sure you want to delete this Data?", _
        "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
          If Button = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
        da.Update(ds, "walkindata")
        If Not ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        ListView1.Items.Remove(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0))
           MsgBox("customer removed in the list.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else
        MsgBox("No Customer Selected.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
        Else
        MsgBox("delete is cancel", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End If
```